# How to recall a variable within the "string map" option in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to sequentially update a series of file, from a tmp file distTmp.RST to sequentially dist1.RST, dist2.RST, etc..

For me, the fileutil package in vmd text interface is not working as follows:

My tcl code (add.tcl):

```
package require fileutil

set F 20.5
set Ff ""

for {set f 0} {$f < 70} {incr f} {
    set F [expr {$F+1}]
    lappend Ff $F
}

puts $Ff


for {set f 0} {$f < 70} {incr f} {
    set M [lindex $Ff $f]
    set N [expr {$f+1}]
    package require fileutil
    ::fileutil::updateInPlace distTmp.RST {string map {WWW $M}}
    ::fileutil::cat dist$N.RST
}
```

========

The error occurring is

```
vmd > source add.tcl
can't find package fileutil
vmd >
```

========

Moreover, when I do not use "fileutil" package, my script is as follows:

```
set F 20.5
set Ff ""

for {set f 0} {$f < 70} {incr f} {
    set F [expr {$F+1}]
    lappend Ff $F
}

puts $Ff


for {set f 0} {$f < 70} {incr f} {

    set M [lindex $Ff $f]
    set N [expr {$f+1}]
    set dat [open "distTmp.RST" r]
    set out [open "dist$N.RST" w]
    while {[gets $dat line] >= 0} {
        set newline [string map {WWW $$M} $line]
        puts $out $newline
    }
}
```

======

But, there is a problem in recalling the variable $M within a string, and my required output files are as follows:

(base) [Prathit@master]~/APP/OnlyAPP/AlphaFold2/770_res/Charmm-Gui_Dimer-units/E2-E2_3222212666/charmm-gui-3222212666/amber/RSTfiles_Equil>head -n +4 dist1.RST dist2.RST

=> dist1.RST <==

&rst iat = -1, -1, r2 = $$M, r2a = $$M,

==> dist2.RST <==

&rst iat = -1, -1, r2 = $$M, r2a = $$M,

==========

In the above, $$M should be sequentially 21.5, 22.5, and so on....

Kindly let me know of a possible solution.

Comment: `string map [list WWW $M] $line` so the variable gets evaluated?

Comment: Once you understand the solution, you'll understand quoting in Tcl :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `fileutil` package is part of tcllib.   Check that your variable `auto_path` includes a path where Tcl can find tcllib and fileutil.
2. Your list for `string map` is in curly braces, so it's using a literal dollar sign for `$M` instead of the value of the variable named M.
   Change curlies to double quotes or use the `list` command, as answered in a comment already.
3. `$$M` is usually not okay in Tcl.  Are you trying to do double interpolation?   If so, I recommend using `set` with one argument, to retrieve a value instead of to set a value.  You can use `$$` in a `subst` command, but that's not my preference.

```
set name John
set var_name name
puts $$var_name   -->  $name
puts [set $var_name]  --> John 
puts [set [set var_name]] --> John
puts [subst $$var_name]   --> John
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the double quote correction worked.